# How to Argsort in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How can I argsort a 25 x 5 x 5 matrix (tensor) along the 2nd axis? Essentially, I am looking for tensorflow's equivalent (function or methodology) to numpy's argsort, e.g. `np.argsort(matrix, 2)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case you could probably use `top_k` which returns the highest `k` values. `k` can be a 1D vector defining how many values to 'top' per dimensions. In your case, if you want the second axis set `k=[0, 5, 0]` might do it.

```
tf.nn.top_k(matrix, k=[0,5,0], sorted=True)
```

I didn't run it tho.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

For reference, [tf.argsort](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort) is now supported in Tensorflow.

**Example**:

```
import tensorflow as tf


tensor = tf.constant(
    [
        [8, 7, 11],
        [5, 3, 4],
        [17, 33, 23],
    ]
)

arg_sort_op = tf.argsort(tensor, axis=-1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = sess.run(arg_sort_op)

print(out)

#  [[1 0 2]
#   [1 2 0]
#   [0 2 1]]
```

Comment: for tensorflow 1.x, `argsort` is in `tf.contrib`: `tf.contrib.framework.argsort`. See [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.12/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/argsort.md) for more details.