# How to find a permutation in a tensor ? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, sorting, tensorflow, permutation

I would like to find a permutation s for a 1D tensor x with this property :
x[s[i]]>x[s[i-1]]   (the permutation is the sort of x)

thank you !

Comment: ...so you want to sort the tensor's values?

Comment: Sounds like [`argsort`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41985060/7207392) (in numpy parlance) to me

Comment: Yes it is like argsort. (I don't want to sort the tensor's values)

Comment: tf.nn.top_k(Tensor,k).indices where k is the length of the tensor